# Office365 Imap not working programatically

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

Trying to connect to imap using MailKit library. While this code works for Gmail and hot mail.
It gives Login Failed error for Office 365.

```
using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger("imap.log")))
{
      client.Timeout = 120000;
      client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 
                      93,SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
      client.Authenticate("xxxxx@xxxxinet.com", "XXXXXPassword");
      client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

      var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);

      foreach (var uid in uids)
      {
         var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);
         // write the message to a file
         message.WriteTo(string.Format("{0}.eml", uid));
     }
     client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: You need to set-up 2FA and obtain an app pass - See [here](https://evermap.com/Tutorial_AMM_AppPasswordOffice365.asp)

Comment: @DarkBee SMTP is working without any issue. Even with app password it's not working for Imap

Comment: Then please post the (full) error you are receiving

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online  Is it possible that basic authentication is no longer supported.?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has Deprecated basic authentication starting from 2023. You can read more about it on their article [Deprecation of Basic authentication in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online)

You need to use Oauth2 authentication [Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)

Comment: Looks like the link you pasted to Authenticate an IMAP is broken @Kalu.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I have corrected the links