# Incoming Mail Server Office 365 Odoo 14

Tags: email, odoo, smtp, imap

I'm not able to connect a incoming mail server in Odoo v14. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) is established successfully without any issue.

But when I try connecting via IMAP or POP I'm getting the following erros:

**IMAP**

Server Name outlook.office365.com

Port    993

Server replied with following exception:
LOGIN failed.

**POP**

Server Name outlook.office365.com

Port    995

Server replied with following exception:
-ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: Where’s your code?  Are you using OAUTH?  You cannot log into office 365 mail services with a password anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office365 Imap not working programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079044/office365-imap-not-working-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the clients addons weren't updated with the newest changes from Odoo's GitHub repository for version `14.0`.

After I updated the newest changes and installed the app `fetchmail_outlook` that had this functionality provided the issue was resolved.